# what does the printf/snprintf format character %N do? (not %n)

Tags: c++

Was going through some old code and found:

```
char buf[...];
int i = 1, j =2;
snprintf(buf, "%d-blah_%d-blah_%N", i, j);
```

Note only two passed vararg parameters, but 3 format strings.

It prints

```
1-blah_2-blah_0
```

Can't find this in any docs.  What does %N do?

Comment: Is `%N` even a thing? I'm having a hard time finding a reference to it.

Comment: Either you're seeing undefined behaviour, or you're seeing an implementation-specific extension.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth plain jane GCC on CentOS.  Nothing special.  snprintf seems to be coming from stdio.h.

Comment: @marathon Just ran on gcc-4.8.1 outputs: "1-blah_2-blah_%N"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to standard documentation (e.g. POSIX [printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html#)) it does nothing defined (so `%N` could be [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and is certainly unspecified behavior in the standards).

However, the GNU [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/libc.html) offers [customizing `printf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Customizing-Printf.html#Customizing-Printf) abilities. Your program might have registered (elsewhere) with [register_printf_function](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Registering-New-Conversions.html#Registering-New-Conversions) something to handle `%N`. This is *not standard* and is *GNU `glibc` specific*
(however, it is a convenient trick, but you can't teach [GCC `format` function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) to know about that trick.).

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting case in Microsoft's CRT. What seems to happen is `%N` is treated as size specifier, but in the end it simply gets ignored.

You can find the source in `<VSDIR>/VC/crt/src/output.c` and for VS2013 you'll find following lines:

```
enum CHARTYPE {
    ...
    CH_SIZE,            /* 'h', 'l', 'L', 'N', 'F', 'w' */
    ...
};
```

`'N'` is also used in lookup state tables. [The documentation says nothing about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6.aspx), nor does it mention `'F'`. Upon closer examination of the source code (`case ST_SIZE`) it turns out `'N'`, `'F'` and `'L'` (despite the docs!) are no-op size modifiers.

So, for VS2013 in your case you'd get `1-blah_2-blah_`, without trailing 0.